# Entitiy Framework: "Update Database from Model" instead of "Generate Database from Model"

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

I have created a Entity Framework 4 model with Visual Studio 2010 and generated a database from it. Now I found myself adding new properties (with default values), changing documentation of columns, changing names of columns, changing types of columns several times. All tasks that do not require much "extra work" in order not to be possible to be achieved automatically (in my humble opinion). Everytime I did "Generate Database from Model" and lost of course the table data.

Is there a way just to update the database's architecture so to say - leaving the table data untouched? Maybe with some user interaction especially when changing types etc.? Or would this functionality be simply too difficult to be realized to work in a reliable way?

Thanks in advance! Cheers, David

Comment: What you see: "I just change the name of these two properties. They're in the same order, and their names mean roughly the same thing, but this is better". What Visual Studio sees: "There was an object with these five properties, and now there's an object with those five properties. Three of them are the same". How do you expect VS to tell which of them is which, or even that they are changed rather than new?

Comment: Just a suggestion.... I usually create the database then update the model from the db. The reason for this is I create a Database called ApplicationModelDB and another called ApplicationDB. The applicationModelDB has no data but that is where I make my updates. Once I get the Entity XML and DB how I want it I apply my DB scripts to my Applcation DB. This accomplishes two things. I can keep track of my SQL necessary to create/update a database or Revert to an older version. AND it allows me to manage the strange quirks of the Entity Framework Designer.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144117/entity-framework-4-update-database-schema-from-model-without-wiping-the-table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Noam Ben-Ami - MSFT1 (Microsoft Employee) answered my question at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/adodotnetentityframework/thread/3adc080f-ee8c-4104-be29-95b2fb3fabe9 as follows:

> We've build the entity designer database power pack to support this. You can download it here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/df3541c3-d833-4b65-b942-989e7ec74c87
>
> It includes a database generation workflow for the designer that does migration, rather than drop/create.
>
> This posting is provided "AS IS" with no warranties, and confers no rights.

I haven't tested the tool yet, but I guess the info might be valueable for others, too.