# Update database schema at runtime with Entity Framework

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework

I'm developing an application with EF4.0.
Between the releases the database schema can change (e.g. column added, table added...).

Is there a way to commit these changes to the customers database when they run the new release? I'm thinking of an function similar to CreateDatabase().

Comment: I'm almost sure that there is nothing like this out of the box. Creating a function to migrate DB schema with no data lost will be very hard task if ever possible. For example, context always has the latest version of storage schema, think about that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 4 - Update database schema from model. Without wiping the table data.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144117/entity-framework-4-update-database-schema-from-model-without-wiping-the-table) I believe this question answers yours.

Comment: No, the question you linked seems to handle the database update from the EF designer. But i'm looking for a way to alter the database when the customer runs an update without running a "handmade" sql script.

Comment: You don't need a "handmade" script. VS will make the script for you. You just need to run it.

Comment: As far as I understand @BLahr wants to update db without loosing data. @BLahr am I right?

Comment: Yes, he does. And the VS 2010 schema migration (formerly "data dude") knows how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Your install procedure must do two things:

- Run a script to update the database
- Install the new program files

To generate the database script use the tools in visual studio, see http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Data-Dude-moving-into-lower-priced-VS-Editions-in-VS-2010-excellent!.aspx