# Entity Framework: How to update database when modifying Model

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-4

In Entity Framework 4 there are the options "Update Model from Database" and "Generate Database from Model". But what I'm missing is an option like

> > Update Database from Model

which reflects the changes made in the model (e.g. adding a new Property or Navigation-Property) by modifying the database schema (e.g. adding a new column). without losing its content.

Does someone know a way to achieve this or is there a t4 template that can perform a schema update without dropping existing tables? (I'm using Visual Studio 2010, .Net 4.0 and SQL Server 2008)

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 4 - Update database schema from model. Without wiping the table data.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144117/entity-framework-4-update-database-schema-from-model-without-wiping-the-table)

Answer (score 1):

Best way that I've found so far is to update the database first, for example adding a column to a table and then update the model from the database. This works well for small changes.