# How does one update live mssql database with code-first migrations in mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have copied the database and launched the website. Now that I add a feature (for example a new property in a Model which leads to a column being created in a certain table), I copy the files to the server and the website gets updated. However, how should I approach the updates of sql server. I know I can generate scripts by using `-Script` in `Update-Database` command, but, what if I forget to do that. Can I somehow review scripts of older migrations so I can run them in my server?

Comment: I think you need to consider source control. We tend to dump .sql scripts for each database change, for each update into our SVN repo for the site in question.

Comment: @DavidHirst Is that being done manually or I can set it up to be done every time I do `Update-Database`?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow? You say "Can I somehow review scripts of older migrations so I can run them in my server?". The answer is yes you can if you use source control for those scripts that you are writing for Update-Database. You can review any older update within your repository and even roll-back your site code and database scripts should you need too. Some source control software will also perform the publishing aspect but I tend to do things manually in my environment.

Comment: @DavidHirst I am not saving any of those scripts at least currently. I do "Update-Database" and the script is generated and executed in the database and that is it, I no longer have any leads to it. Does that mean I have to start saving them somewhere in my application? Or maybe I am mistaken and they are actually being saved somewhere but I cannot find them? P.S. These scripts are being generated by `EF` or whatever is responsible for that. The only thing that I have to do with them being generated is that I, as I gave an example in the question, added a new property in a Model.

Comment: I see, well take a look at this thread I believe this is what your looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153047/entity-framework-4-0-generate-change-script

Comment: I am not a fan of having to use other software. I am pretty sure this can be done in VS, I just cannot find where. On the other hand, if I find nothing else to go with, I guess I will use some software for that. Or I will have to remember to save the script every single time :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Entity Framework Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ591621.aspx) you can simply use the Database Initializer `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`.  On your development machine you perform all your work with the migrations, testing, etc, and when you are happy with the result, send the working Migrations to the server with your updated code base, then restart the server.  The context does the rest.

> If you are deploying your application you may want it to automatically upgrade the database (by applying any pending migrations) when the application launches. You can do this by registering the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion database initializer. A database initializer simply contains some logic that is used to make sure the database is setup correctly. This logic is run the first time the context is used within the application process (AppDomain).

Comment: Looks promising! Will try that one as soon as possible. Thanks!

Comment: It is a *hugely* bad idea to allow Entity Framework to do anything against your production database. EF migrations are intended for development purposes only. For more information on how to handle this properly, see http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/