# Create the Provider db tables after RecreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-4, asp.net-membership

I'm new to EF4, usign CPT4 Code-First and SQLExpress (MVC2 + Ninject but does not matter). It's working good but I do have one question/problem. When I change my model the database get drop and created back because I added this line in my OnApplicationStart()

```
{ Database.SetInitializer<CorpiqDb>(new RecreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<CorpiqDb>()); }
```

But I use the Applications Services (membership and role management) that I first created using aspnet_regsql.exe But I don't want to have to run this everytime my model changes, is it possible to have a script that will add these features to my DB? As for right now, after a change to my model I get this error : 
Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done, and it's working quite well, is that I have two seprates DBs, one for my domain and one other for asp.net Membership. When my model changes I call an action that drop model's database and remove users from the membership's one. Event better, I can seed my new database with data I want to have for my test.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [database generation power pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144117/entity-framework-4-update-database-schema-from-model-without-wiping-the-table). It removes the necessity to drop the DB when updating the schema.

Comment: Thanks Craig, can it be controlled by code or we have to use a Wizzard? I read your link and it does not seems to be what I'm looking for, I want the database to be generated only by code for unit testing purpose and migration. For now it's working but I don't get the Applications Services tables and stored proc...

Comment: It produces a script. You can do whatever you want with that script.