# In Visual Studio 2012, when you add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model (*.edmx)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

In Visual Studio 2012, when you add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model (*.edmx), it includes the T4 templates for the context and model classes as sub-items of the EDMX file. For example, if you add MyModel.edmx, it will have 4 sub-items as follows:

1. MyModel.Context.tt
2. MyModel.Designer.cs (in C# projects)
3. MyModel.edmx.diagram
4. MyModel.tt (model classes)

Question: When I change database, then I can update MyModel.Context automaticaly. If I change any model class (adding/deleting/updating any models or its properties) that is in MyModel.tt, Does database change automaticaly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not. the edmx file can be used to generate a new db schema,
just right click on the demx designer -> choose generate db from model.

to update an existing model see:

[Entity Framework 4 - Update database schema from model. Without wiping the table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144117/entity-framework-4-update-database-schema-from-model-without-wiping-the-table)

Answer (score 0):

The Database changes automatically only if you're using Code First approach, which you're not, since you're using EDMX. Once you use EDMX you are using either Model First or Database First.

If you want your Database to change automatically, than you'll have to switch to Code First.